# UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad localization

Tags: localization, ios4, uikeyboard

I noticed that UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad was added in iOS 4.1, and started using it.  During the course of my testing, I switched both the language and region to French in the International section of Settings.  I expected the decimal key on the keypad in my app to change from a "." to a "," but it didn't.

All I'm doing is this:

```
_textFieldUnitCost.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem for me in German. I hoped to replace UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation with the new DecimalPad, but without considering the region format not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 4.2.1 the decimal key on the keypad now changes from a "." to "," when switching to a language/region that uses a ","

Answer (score 0):

One way around it is to just accept the punctuation because it is a decimalpad and than change it when you pass it as a string to display.

```
NSString *firstString = @"102.08", *finalString;

finalString = [[firstString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"." withString:@","];
//string value returns 102,08
```

That will work if you just need to display. It will not work if your doing math with that string. You actually can't. Now you can store it as a float and then when you convert to a string you do those 2 lines of code